# C++ using a priority queue of objects

Tags: c++, stl, queue

I want to make a priority queue of objects, Specifically pair of (int, int). The queue should contain pairs with a priority assigned to them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;    

class saPair{
public:
    int s;
    int a;
    double priority;
    saPair(int s, int a, double priority){
        this->s = s;
        this->a = a;
        this->priority = priority;
    }
};

// the priority menmber variable determines the priority in the queue
// highest priority pair of (int, int) stays on the top
bool operator< (const saPair& x, const saPair& y) {
    return x.priority < y.priority;
}


int main()
{
    priority_queue<saPair> pq;
    pq.push(saPair(0,0, 0.3));
    pq.push(saPair(0,1, 0.1));
    pq.push(saPair(0,3, 0.5));
    pq.push(saPair(0,3, 5));

    cout << pq.top().a << endl;
    pq.pop();
    cout << pq.top().a << endl;
    pq.pop();
    cout << pq.top().a << endl;


}
```

As you can see, the pair (0,3) has highest priority so it stays on the top. But the problem with my implementation is that, if I add (0,3) pair again with different priority, I add a new element to the queue, instead of replacing the priority of the already existing (0,3) pair.

I feel like I choose the wrong data structure for my requirement. I tried map taking key value, by defining a new saPair(int, int) class with operating overload for < operator. But even that doesn't seem to work properly..

Any suggestions on how to proceed? or modify

Comment: Its a queue so there is no requirement about uniqueness. Maybe what you want is a set?!

Comment: Yes. there is no way to use queue directly. I am looking for an alternative data structure. It feels like a common occurring data structure but i am not able to find a simple solution to it. An object, and a corresponding priority assigned to the object. Sort the objects in the priority order. I need a data structure satisfying this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need a multi-key access to your container: you want to sort it by priority (or at least have a binary heap by priority as in `priority_queue`), and you want the pair values to be unique, so you'll need a pair value lookup too.

There is no default solution for that in standard library, but it shouldn't be too hard to craft your own.

I'd suggest simply storing an additional `std::set<saPair>` to check if the pair is already in your container. This way you can keep your `priority_queue` the way it is, and it won't take too much effort to implement.

Don't forget to add `operator<` to `saPair` though (or replace it by `std::pair`), otherwise `std::set` would not be able to work with it.

Another option is just manually check your `priority_queue` for a pair every time you add it. While asymptotically worse than `std::set` solution, this might very well be faster in practice, and it will save you some space. However I think the code would be much cleaner if you go with `std::set`.

Yet another solution is `boost::multi_index`, which allows you to easily construct any multi-indexed container you want. However I don't think it'll let you capitalize on the fact that you don't need a strong ordering by priority, so it won't have a linear contiguous layout like `priority_queue` does.